# Haskell parser created with Alex and Happy doesn't work because of main function, someone can tell me why?

Tags: parsing, haskell, lexer, happy, alex

Basically i just created a parser to print the derivation tree of a Reverse Polish Notation expression, which recognizes regular expression built in RPN, tokenizes them recognizes only the expressions RPN built-like and should return the derivation tree.
The problem is that the main function doesn't do its work, but if i run manually what's inside the main function, then it just do what it is supposed to do!

### --Alex lexer

Recognizes all the tokens which can be find in a RPN expression: int numbers and chars for basic operations +,-,*,/

```
{
    module Lexical (Token(..), lexer) where
}

%wrapper "basic"

$digit = [0-9]
@int = $digit+

tokens :-
    $white+     ;
    "--".*      ;
    \+          {\s -> TokenPlus}
    \-          {\s -> TokenMinus}
    \*          {\s -> TokenTimes}
    \/          {\s -> TokenDiv}
    @int        {\s -> TokenInt (read s)}

{
data Token
    = TokenPlus
    | TokenMinus
    | TokenTimes
    | TokenDiv
    | TokenInt Int
    deriving (Eq,Show)

            
lexer = alexScanTokens
}
```

### --Happy parser

Recognizes all the expressions built in RPN and should print the equivalent derivation tree using the data constructor Exp. For the context, i know i could even use the Tree data constructor but Exp helps me understand better how i want my expressions to be printed.

```
{
module Main where
import Lexical
}

%name calc
%tokentype {Token}
%error {parseError}

%token
    '+'         {TokenPlus}
    '-'         {TokenMinus}
    '*'         {TokenTimes}
    '/'         {TokenDiv}
    int         {TokenInt $$}

%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'

%%

Exp : Exp Exp '+'       { Plus $1 $2 }
    | Exp Exp '-'       { Minus $1 $2 }
    | Exp Exp '*'       { Times $1 $2 }
    | Exp Exp '/'       { Div $1 $2 }
    | int               { Int $1 }

{
parseError :: [Token] -> a
parseError _ = error "ParseError"

data Exp = Plus Exp Exp
         | Minus Exp Exp
         | Times Exp Exp
         | Div Exp Exp
         | Int Int 
         deriving (Eq, Show)

main = do
        s <- getContents
        print(calc (lexer s))
}
```

The problem is in the main function:
if i just run for example

```
print (calc (lexer "3 4 5 + *"))
```

it just returns what i expect, which is:

```
Times (Int 3) (Plus (Int 4) (Int 5))
```

but if i execute "happy parser.y" and then "ghci parser.hs", it will compile fine but as soon as i call the main function, it lets me write the RPN expressions i want but it just does or prints nothing!
If someone can help me i will be so grateful

Comment: Did you use Ctrl+D to end the stream?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem if i use Ctrl+D to end the stream, the main gives me:               
*** Exception: lexical error
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at .\\Lexical.hs:491:32 in main:Lexical

Comment: well likely because the parser can not handle new lines.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you man, really!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question, I think that you see `getContents` as a "prompt" that reads a line and then ends. But `getContents` reads *all* lines until the stream closes. You can in most shells close the stream with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, so then `getContents` is finished.

If you want to parse only a single line, you use [**`getLine :: IO String`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:getLine):

```
main = do
  s <- getLine
  print (calc (lexer s))
```

Comment: Holy cow man, it worked, didn't even think about getLine. Thank you so much, i was becoming stupid on a really simple thing! Can you just explain me one more thing, which is why i can't close with Ctrl+D the stream of getContents?

Comment: @DanielGattesco: well it depends on the shell how you close a stream, although Ctrl+D is quite common. Perhaps the parser you created does not work with `\n`/`\r`.